# What is meant by the following operation?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I cannot understand what is meant by following operation in embedded C?

```
NVIC_ICPR |= 1 << (vector_number%32);
```

From the reference manual, I found that

- Vector number — the value stored on the stack when an interrupt is serviced.
- IRQ number — non-core interrupt source count, which is the vector number minus
  16.

But why is it modular division by 32?

Comment: `x%32` is equivalent to `x&31`: a logical and on the least significant 5 bits.

Comment: @j.aug.: The idea is same but check the edit please. ICPR is clear pending control register

Comment: Yeah understood, thankyou :)

Comment: @mouviciel `x%32` is _not_ the equivalent to `x&31` when `x < 0`.

Comment: `vector_number%32` is not "modular division by 32" when `vector_number` is `int`.  Post types/declarations of `vector_number, NVIC_ICPR`

Comment: @chux - I doubt that low level interrupt handling involves negative integers.

Comment: @mouviciel Compiler cannot assume with `int x`, that `x >= 0`.  `x%32` and `x&31` will emit different code.  In an interrupt handle, best to use highly efficient code, which in this case, if a performance difference exists,  is certainly `x&31` - or better - use `unsigned x` and avoid the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically a register with `32` bits in it.

This removes pending state of one or more interrupts within a group of `32`. Each bit represents an interrupt number from `IRQ0 - IRQ31` `(Vector number from 16 - 47)`.
Writing 1 will remove the pending state. Writing 0 has no effect.

An important point is you should use it like this

```
NVIC_ICPR |= 1U << (vector_number%32);
```

This ensures that this will be unsigned int arithmetic - it saves you from UB which arises when `vector_number=31`. (chux pointed this).

Comment: Here the `vector_number = INT_UART0 -16;` and `INT_UART0` is defined as 28 as /**< UART0 status/error interrupt */. So which bit would be set in the NVIC_ICPR register?

Comment: @j.aug.: `12%32 = 12` and `1<<12` is `00000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000`

Comment: With 32-bit `int` and `vector_number == 31`, `1 << (vector_number%32);` is UB. Better to use `1u << (vector_number%32);` .

Comment: I have my interrupt handler as follows for LIN transmission over uart0 `void FTM0_IRQHandler()
  {  
    if (1==((FTM0_C0SC & FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK)>>FTM_CnSC_CHF_SHIFT) )
   {
    (void)FTM0_C0SC;
    FTM0_C0SC ^= FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK;
    FTM0_C0V = FTM0_C0V + 391 ;
    
    if (LED_counter>=50){
     /* Toggle LED for LIN transmission */
     /* Reset counter */
     LED0_TOGGLE;
     LED_counter = 0;
    }
    LED_counter++;
   }
  }` Though I donot have any LIN transmission to my slave, the led is blinking, Iam not understanding from where the interrupt has been generated.

Comment: @chux.: Thanks for pointing out and as you can see OP posted in comment.